# Flexslider - Firefox won't play Vimeo Video

Tags: firefox, vimeo, flexslider

I have a vimeo video embedded on slide 1 of my Flexslider slider, and I can play the video fine in Chrome and Safari, but not on Firefox. The video iframe loads, just I can't click and play the video.

Here is my iFrame in one of the `<li>...</li>` sections for slide 1 (I replaced the video id with 68824907 for demonstration):

```
<iframe id="carousel-video" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/68824907?api=1&amp;player_id=carousel-video" style="margin: 83px 0 0 25px; position: absolute;" width="415" height="233" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Here is my Flexslider call script:

```
$(".flexslider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide", animationLoop: true,
    controlNav: true, directionNav: false, smoothHeight: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 7000, animationSpeed: 700, easing: 'easeOutQuint',
    before: function(slider){
        $f($('#carousel-video')[0]).api('pause');
    }
});
```

It seems like the issue is the section "animation: "slide"" for the flexslider call, since if I remove it I can play Vimeo videos fine, but without that line the slider won't move. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works on Firefox, when I'm pasting the iframe into a slide of the flexslider original demo. Do you work on a Mac? I had several strange issues with the CSS-transitions in the flexslider, which are turned on by default in Flexslider 2. Maybe you could try to turn them off by using:

**useCSS: false**

while initializing the flexslider.